# Spring Tool Suite change key binding autocompletion

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, spring-tool-suite

How do I change the keybinding for code autocompletion? <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is just horrible. I would like to have <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.
But under `Window->Preferences->General->Keys->Content Assist` I can not choose <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to `Window`-> `Preferences` -> `General` -> `Keys` and type `content assist`.
2. Copy this text -> `Alt+Space`.
3. Right click on `Binding` text field.
4. Paste.
5. Apply, OK.
6. Enjoy.

Comment: Big thx. Now it works. Pressing Alt+Space, didn't work, but clearing the field and pasting Alt+Space did the job!